# Get missing members of abstract base class

Tags: c++, inheritance

I tried to overwrite all methods of an abstract base class but i didn't get all as it seems.

I build the project with msbuild , the project was generated by cmake.

The MSVC++ 2012 compiler complains with the error `error C2259: 'Derived' : cannot instantiate abstract class`.

So the question is, how to force the compiler to tell me the missing method names that the class is no longer abstract (and all methods got specified)?

Comment: Can you show your code regarding creating object from abstract class?

Comment: You might find the first answer to this question useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1699224/method-for-solving-error-cannot-instantiate-abstract-class

Comment: @MatthewWalton i am building the project with msbuild but the error message is the same, just without the information about the missing definition

Comment: You did not implement all abstract methods of the interface in your derived class.

Comment: @mjs i made the question more clearly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at the Output window, not the Error List. My error list, for instance, says:

```
error C2259: 'Derived' : cannot instantiate abstract class
```

but my Output says:

```
1>c:\users\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\testcpp\test.cpp(18): error C2259: 'Derived' : cannot instantiate abstract class
1>          due to following members:
1>          'void Base::bar(void)' : is abstract
1>          c:\users\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\testcpp\test.cpp(8) : see declaration of 'Base::bar'
```

A lot of MSVC error messages give details on succeeding lines, and unfortunately those usually don't make their way into the Error List.